# Low resolution backgrounds when using GridViewPager

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to use sharp, high resolution backgrounds for my `GridViewPager` in an Android Wearable project.  But it seems the GridViewPager automatically scales and pans any backgrounds supplied to it via `getBackground( row, col )` in the PagerAdapter.  Any way to prevent this from happening?  I've tried different resolution images, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Even the GridViewPager example project shows pixelated backgrounds (they are zoomed in and not completely visible from edge to edge).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So it turn out it was a build problem.  When I first tried higher res images, they never made it to the emulator.  Not sure if it is related to Android Studio or the Wear emulators, but doing a project clean and rebuild with higher res images seemed to do the trick...